# Unit testing WCF Rest Service with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, rest

I created a wcf rest service and added a entity Framework database, having issues doing unit testing some of the methods. I get error asserting the connection string is not there or invalid. I am using the actual database for testing. Firstly, i copied in the web.config file into the test project, is there any thing else i need to do, such as editing this config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your test project is not a web project, remember to rename the config file to app.config

Comment: I had a suspicion this was it. I will rename it to app.config. In the actual project it is called web.config.

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you for teaching me something today. David.

Comment: Now search the execution directories and look for *.config files.  To add another thought to the Config file lesson